# How can i drag an element through a straight line in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm wanting to make a slider and when the draggable object gets to a certain spot a text is going to be shown.

What things can I use or what would be the best approach to achieve this? Because I've been looking at different things like the "HTML drag and drop API" or the "Enter/Leave & List Transitions" in the Vue documentation, but I'm confused and don't know where to start.

To make an idea, in this image I should be able to grab the circle, move it straight up (without chance of going out the line) and at a certain point of the arrow, another text would need to be shown.

[image]

If someone can help me with this I will be very thankful.

Comment: You can simply listen for `@mousedown`, `@mouseup` and `@mousemove` - first and second will toggle/untoggle a flag showing whether the use is just moving the mouse or dragging the slider. The third event will actually give you the coordinates - you will use only Y coordinate, to move the slider. Then you will have a watcher for the slider Y coordinate - and when it reaches the threshold - the watcher should raise another flag, signaling about showing the text.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that way, I think I have it much more clear now! Thanks for commenting.